# ImageView Scale Only Height and keep width match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to ImageView Scale Only Height and keep width match_parent so that width can be taken as it

Here is my code can you please give me suggestion.

```
      <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view_image"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"


            card_view:elevation="0dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_name"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp">

            </ImageView>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I want to give height as 140 fix and image should scale to that height.

Comment: what do you mean when you say you want to match parent as width but height scalable?
Do you mean your height of ImageView should be flexible with the height of the image?

Comment: i want to give height as 140 fix and image should scale to that height.

Comment: And you don't mind your image getting stretched weirdly widthwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you ask the scale type. You can use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

If I understand the problem correctly, you can fix it by adding the above code.
If this is not the solution, you will understand the subject more clearly if you examine the [link](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide).

Comment: Hi Umut thanks for kind response i want to scale only height their is option with android:scaleY but how to use it i am not sure.

Comment: If you draw a sample image and add into the question what do you want to do, we understand easier. Because I think it can be done with scaleType.

Comment: Also, scaleY usage is simple. If you want to scale height for example 1.5 times the size of heights, you set android:scaleY="1.5".

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood,
If you use a linear layout for the parent then you can use the android:layout_weight and assign it a value of 1 and keep the android:layout_height to 0dp. This will allow your image to scale as much as possible as it will not allow any space to be left unused on the screen.

```
<LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Tom image is not visible after set up height to zero

Comment: Is it not visible after running the app or in the XML editor

Answer (score 1):

the scaleY attribute used to scale the view in Y-direction, you can check it out by giving it an integer value greater than one.
SEE BELOW CODE.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:scaleY="3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    />
```

But it may stretch your imageView which will look ugly so try to use scaleType attribute as shown below:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use the following setting

```
 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/img"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="140dp">
```

The image view will take full match parent as width and 140dp as height but the image inside ImageView will still maintain its aspect ratio and will stretch to only either end (either to width or to height) while maintaining the aspect ratio.

For example: if you have 100*70 dimension image then your image after rendering in the ImageView will be taking 140dp height and 200dp width to maintain aspect ratio despite having a lot of extra room available in width(width been match_parent)

But if you want your image to take full space of your Imageview without worrying about aspect ratio then you can use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

fitXY make sure the image is stretched to full available space.

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/img"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  android:layout_height="140dp">
```

For example: if you have the same 100*70 dimension image then your image after rendering in the ImageView will be taking 140dp height and width will depend upon the dimension of the device as available width is full width allocated to parent view (width been match_parent) and the image will be stretched and will be out of aspect ratio.